# Variantes de "en début d'année / d'après-midi / de mois"

Tags: expressions, prépositions, articles

Selon [ce dictionnaire](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/d%C3%A9but), on dit:

> en début d'année / d'après-midi / de mois / ...

Peut-on dire ces expressions avec un article défini ?

> en début de l'année / de l'après-midi / **du** mois / ...

Une autre question: On dit aussi "au début de ...". Peut-on dire alors les expressions suivantes ?

> au début d'année / d'après-midi / de mois / ...

ou

> au début de l'année / de l'après-midi / du mois / ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On dira en effet :

> en début d'année / d'après-midi / de mois / ...

et

> au début de l'année / de l'après-midi / du mois / ...

mais pas les autres propositions.

- Le premier (en début de) a un sens général
- Le second (au début de / au début) a un sens précis

ex :

- En début d'année (i.e. tous les ans ou presque), je vais toujours en vacances à la mer
- Au début de l'année (i.e. cette année en cours), j'étais en vacances à la mer

ou encore

- On se retrouve en début de soirée ! (heure indéterminée, soirée indéterminée : peut être aujourd'hui, demain, etc. entre 19h et 21h environ)
- Nous nous sommes vu au début de la soirée (de cette soirée qui est en cours ou dont on parle)